# Volley GET JsonObjectRequest with JSONObjectParameter doesn't work at all

Tags: java, android, json, controller, android-volley

I've got a problem with Volley request - I want to send GET (another similiar POST also) request with `JSONObject` param (user having password and login) to authorize user and send back full user data. Although I can see during debugging that `mRequestBody` is correct `JSON` but I cannot receive it by my controller -

```
private void processLogin() throws JSONException {
    this.user.setLogin(this.loginText.getText().toString());
    this.user.setPassword(this.passwordText.getText().toString());
    final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(this.user));

    final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, UrlHelper.loginUrl, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            user = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), User.class);
            if (user.getUserId().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.ERROR))) {
                onLoginFailed();
            } else {
                onLoginSuccess(user);
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return headers;
        }
    };
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);
}
```

Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loginTest", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
public User someMethod(@RequestBody User user) throws SQLException {
    return userService.authenticateUser(user.getLogin(), user.getPassword());
}
```

Without annotation `@RequestBody` I it process but User in `param` is empty, so I process User with null password and login. Recently I did it by `StringRequest` Please, help me. :)

Answer (score 0):

As a part of the HTTP specs, GET requests have no body. You can create and send GET requests with a body though, but that's meaningless since the body has no semantic meaning in the GET method specification. I don't know too much about Spring, but my guess is that Spring is probably ignoring the body of the request because it's a GET method. You should send and receive the request as POST if your intention is to put something inside the body.

Comment: Okey, so I change my method to POST, use StringRequest and implement getBodyContentType()  and getBody() methods for it and I improve my controller method. Thanks for your help :)